# How to get keys from map Object with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this structure below:

```
/* Wrapper to format cellphone configuration list for selectors. */
    function buildConfiguration(){
        return {
            "Item 1": {
                name: {
                    "aaa": 1,
                },
                blue: {
                },
                green: {
                },
                black: {
                },
                yellow: {
                }
            },

            "item 2": {
                name: {
                    "aaa 5": 1,
                    "bbb 6": 2,
                    "ccc 7": 3
                },
                blue: {
               },
                green: {
               },
               black: {
               },
               yellow: {
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

I would like get the keys from this map object.

I'm trying this console.log(Object.keys(buildConfiguration));

but return 0 itens.

Could please help me?

Comment: This question is not related angularjs.

Comment: buildConfiguration is a function, don't forget the `()`

Comment: you need to invoke the buildConfiguration function like this console.log(Object.keys(buildConfiguration()));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call that function like `buildConfiguration()` and you're done

```js
function buildConfiguration(){
        return {
            "Item 1": {
                name: {
                    "aaa": 1,
                },
                blue: {
                },
                green: {
                },
                black: {
                },
                yellow: {
                }
            },

            "item 2": {
                name: {
                    "aaa 5": 1,
                    "bbb 6": 2,
                    "ccc 7": 3
                },
                blue: {
               },
                green: {
               },
               black: {
               },
               yellow: {
               }
           }
       }
   } 
   
   
   console.log(Object.keys(buildConfiguration()))
```